# Aggregation in SQL (Teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata, aggregation

I'm having a little trouble finding out how to solve this.

On the select clause, when I remove the value "(delta.dec_rev-delta.nov_rev)/delta.nov_rev" -- which is an aggregate function -- everything is fine.

However, once I try to add my calculation in, I get the error

> Selected non-aggregate values must be part of the associated group

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT 
    subquery.var1, 
    subquery.var2, 
    (subquery.varX - subquery.varY) / subquery.varX
#Take data from subquery
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         m.var1, t.var2 
         COUNT(DISTINCT(t.var3a)) AS var3, 
         SUM(var4a) / var3 AS var4, 
         EXTRACT(MONTH from n) AS z, 
         (CASE WHEN z=11 THEN var4) AS varX, 
         (CASE WHEN z=12 THEN var4) AS varY
     FROM 
         table1 m 
     JOIN 
         table2 t ON m.var = t.var 
     GROUP BY 
         m.var1, t.var2, z) AS subquery
#Form a new group
GROUP BY 
    subquery.var1, subquery.var2
ORDER BY 
    (subquery.varX - subquery.varY) / subquery.varX
```

I tried doing it without a subquery. I can't figure out how to aggregate on var1.

It also works fine with out the function "(subquery.varX-subquery.varY)/subquery.varX" but thats exactly the values I'm looking for, aggregated on var1 and var2

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense (and Teradata also agrees).  You are including non aggregate columns (`varX` and `varY`) in a `GROUP BY` select statement.

Comment: I thought you HAD to include non-aggregate columns in a group :/

Edit - I just took the sum of varX and varY in the top function of the parent querry, and the data seems to be correct.

Comment: No, the opposite actually :-) (except for MySQL which allows this).  Just think about the problem: you told Teradata to aggregate over multiple records for `var1` and `var2`, but it has no way of knowing _which_ values to take for `varX` and `varY`.

Comment: Good on you, taking the sum should fix it.

Comment: In fact you probably don't need a Derived Table at all. Teradata allows to reuse an alias within the same level, so remove the `z` from `GROUP BY` and then it's the same as the outer and you can remove it.